# PHP - Censor the middle of a string

Tags: php, string

I wan't with PHP script that the middle part from one string will get censored.

For example:
**developer@example.com**,
Will turn into:
**develo*********le.com**.

What would be a clean and efficient way to do this?

My code at the moment:

```
                    $target = "example@example.com";
                    $count = strlen($target) - 7;
                    $asterix = '';

                    for ($a = 0; $a <= $count; $a++) {
                        $asterix .= '*';
                    }

                    $output = substr($target, 0, 4) . $asterix . substr($target, -3);

                    echo $output;
```

**EDIT**

All of you are hard-coding the astrixes (******) in it... i want it to be exact.

**It's solved bij Sadiq. You're the real MVP man.**

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your attempt a solution, and we can offer feedback.

Comment: _“clean and efficient”_ comes after you have tried something yourself … otherwise this is just the typical “someone please write my code” type of question.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. One of them is to use [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

Comment: Added my code to it now, i haven't added it not because i want others to do it... i haven't add it because i tought it would be a very messy way. I'm still new to this and just wanna learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$target = "example@example.com";
$count = strlen($target) - 7;
$output = substr_replace($target, str_repeat('*', $count), 4, $count);
echo $output;
```

It takes advantage of [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) and [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php).

Comment: thankyou, i didn't know about str_repeat, gonna look it up right now! atleast someone who is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's substr function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
$emailAddr = "developer@mydomain.com";
$emailAddrHidden = substr($emailAddr, 0, 6) . "*******" . substr($emailAddr, -6, 6);

echo $emailAddrHidden;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i already figured that one, my problem is, i want the '*********' be the exact amount of whats covered.

if someone has a really short email address, that there will be only some asterix's and someone with a long email address that there will be alot of asterix's (*)

Answer (score 0):

This code will work when the length of the email address changes:

```
$email = 'developer@example.com';
$length = strlen($email); //Find the string length
$astr='';
for ($i=1;$i<=$length-12;$i++){$astr .= '*';}
echo substr($email, 0, 6) . $astr . substr($email, -6 , 6);
```

Comment: This should add the correct number of asterisks

Comment: Extreme edge case, but this fails for really short email addresses.

Comment: thanks, but that's kinda the same as what i've had.... lol =P

Comment: Ya but he wanted the *** to be exact so I added the $astr part. Sadiq seems to have the best answer though